# How to Set Naviation and Scrollbar in Eclipse RCP Browser?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm using eclipse rcp and load html content into browser I want to set scrollbar , and naviation buttons like previouse, next and split browser content on perticuarl event

```
Is there any example which will enable me chane in existing code or any eclipse rcp browser layout which having scrollbar(progressbar) with listener event.
```

### following code will enable me to read epub unzip html content file.

```
public class CliskDisplay {

@PostConstruct
public static void createControls(Composite parent) throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException, IOException {
    final Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
    String fullHtml = DeviceListPart.html;
    String[] parts = fullHtml.split("#");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
    String part2 = parts[1];
    String mysz2 = part1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    String input_file = "D:/ePubWork/zip/OEBPS/" + mysz2;
    browser.setUrl(input_file);
}
```

### }

Comment: What has JavaFX got to do with this? Inside the browser control it is just normal HTML, CSS, Javascript like any other browser.

Comment: @greg-449 I have rendered epub file content in swt.broweser beed to add scrollbar (progressbar) in swt.browser and add controls for navigating browser (HTML) content.